# Only select nodes without a namespace/prefix in PHP DOM?

Tags: php, xml, dom, namespaces

I'm trying to read some RSS feeds with DOM in PHP like this one:

```
    <channel>
        <atom:link href='' rel='self' type='application/rss+xml' />
        <title>TechStuff</title>
        <link>http://www.howstuffworks.com</link>
```

To grab the link (`<link></link>`) I use this piece of code:

```
    $doc->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0);
```

It works in all other RSS feeds that I have tried. But this one has placed `<atom:link>` before `<link>`, which means that it grabs `<atom:link>` instead.

So how do I do to only select nodes without a namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell whether a node has a namespace by checking `->prefix` or `->namespaceURI`:

```
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('link') as $link) {
    if (strlen($link->prefix)) {
        continue;
    }
    // $link does not have prefix
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve it by using [DOMXPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) and [XPath syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) instead.

Comment: Would be nice if you add a little example how (just an exemplary xpath, the xpath-function names should then speak for themselves)

Answer (score 1):

Here is DOMXPath example:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$linkPath = $xpath->query("/rss/channel/link");
$link = $linkPath->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

On a similar XML hierarchy, it worked for me.